# What's the proper term for materialising a generator into a container

Tags: python, terminology

In Python we can generate sequences of data, but only make them concrete when we consume the generator, or evaluate the mapping or range.

What is the term for this? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18078533/1084416) where the term materialized is used:

> Just call `list()` on the generator for those occasions you need the result to be materialized

Just to be clear, in Python 2 we have, for example:

```
>>> range(5)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but in Python 3 we have:

```
>>> range(5)
range(0, 5)
```

We can consume this and materialise it into a list:

```
>>> list(_)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A section about parsing in [PEP 255 - Simple Generators](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/) says:

> programs can be very large, so no a priori bound can be placed on the memory needed to materialize the whole parse

Is materialise the correct term, or is there something else?

Comment: I'm not aware of an 'official term'. If a PEP uses 'materialize', then that's as formal as you are going to get.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That was your answer I linked. It's the term I would use but I just [answered another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35016510/1084416) and wanted to be sure before using it.

Comment: I don't think a term exists because I think the concept isn't complete. You can't "materialize" a generator because it might be infinite. Thus, a generator can only _yield_ values, it is not guaranteed to _result in_ a finite thing. … _expectation value_?

Comment: @kojiro You could say the same with limited memory, but materialising a `range` seems a reasonable thing to talk about, even if it's impossible.

Comment: @kojiro In the [Functional Programming HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html) section on [Generator expressions and list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/functional.html#generator-expressions-and-list-comprehensions) it says: *Generator expressions return an iterator that computes the values as necessary, not needing to materialize all the values at once*

Comment: @PeterWood We can get very deep into semantics here. Generator _expressions_ return an _iterator_, but it is that iterator that you are talking about consuming. Frequently, we refer to the result of a generator expression as "a generator" without too much pain.